# Open multiple projects in Sublime Text 3 editor

Tags: netbeans, sublimetext3

How can I open multiple projects/folders in Sublime Text 3?

Basically what happen is when I try to open a new project folder in Sublime Text 3 like in Netbeans we open a multiple project, but here it dose open a new folder in a separate window.

Also I want to set word wrap option as false (default) each time I open Sublime Text 3. What can I try?

Comment: Drag it your folder into `sublime text 3 sidebar`. That's it.

Comment: Thanks , and how about the word wrap ? i want to make it false by default.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.whatibroke.com/?p=733) link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways that you can do is.

```
1) Select the option from Project -> Add project to folder and select project menu.
2) You can also drag your folder to the sublime.
```

For wordwrap follow the step :

```
 Preference menu -> setting_user -> add below line into it.
"word_wrap": "false"
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

From terminal solution.

```
subl -a your/path/to/project
```

This will append the project in your current window of sublime.